# Weighted Twist of Vandermonde's Identity

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, hypergeometric-function

I've been stuck on the following expression, trying to determine a "simple" closed form for it:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\frac{1}{m-i}{x-a \choose i-a}{2m-x-b \choose m-1-i-b}.$$

I feel like there should be an obvious simplification based on where it is derived from, but who knows, maybe I'm crazy. As stated in the title, this can be viewed as a weighted twist of Vandermonde's identity, by setting $i\leftarrow i+a$ and adjusting the limits:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{m-1-a-b}\frac{1}{m-i-a}{x-a \choose i}{2m-x-b \choose m-1-a-b-i}.$$ Now, without the leading weight term $\frac{1}{m-i-a}$ the sum would just be ${2m-a-b \choose m-1-a-b}$ by Vandermonde's identity. But with the weighted term, I'm pretty lost.

Comment: Hmm, Mathematica has some luck with the $b=0$ case, e.g. [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B1%2F%28m+-+i%29+Binomial%5Bx+-+5%2C+i+-+5%5D+Binomial%5B2+m+-+x%2C+++++++m+-+1+-+i%5D%2C+%7Bi%2C+0%2C+m+-+1%7D%5D).

Comment: Yeah, with b=0 you can actually fold the weight term into the 2nd binomial (3rd term), to get $({2m-a+1 \choose m-a}-{x-a \choose m-a})/(2m+1-x)$